# UISearchBar below navigation bar, how to make it NOT push nav bar up when active?

Tags: uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Touching the search bar in an apple app I am developing causes the navigation bar to be hidden.

Here are two screenshots to demonstrate:

[image: screenshot of an apple phone screen, showing a blank app screen with 'Search' written on the navigation bar. A search box is displayed below this navigation bar]

[image: screenshot of an apple phone screen, showing an open search box, with cursor. There is a cancel button to the right of the search box, and a keyboard is displayed in the bottom half of the screen]

When you tap on the search bar, it pushes the navigation bar up, off the top of the screen. How can I make it stay in place when clicking search?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One method is to prevent the searchBar from accessing the navigationBar - implement

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return nil;
}
```

in the viewController assigned as the UISearchBar's delegate (or UISearchDisplayController's delegate).

If you still need to access the navigationController elsewhere in the controller, use

```
super.navigationController
```

in place of

```
self.navigationController
```

Comment: this got rid of my problem, but when I clicked on a cell in the table view, it crashed